# Google Geocharts: Regions and Markers on same map?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm experimenting with Google's [GeoCharts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart).  I have state data and city data that I want to display over the city data.  This means I want to use the geochart `regions` and `markers` display mode at the same time.  Can this be done, or faked?  I can't seem to find a way but was wondering if anyone else has had success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in documentation `mode` parameter could be `region` or `marker`. So they could not be used together. I would recommend you to try [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/) library which supports such kind of behavior.

Answer (score 3):

with some CSS hacking you can use the markers mode and color the region you want. 
It's not easy, you would have to know wich 'child' path of the svg map you want to color and make advanced css rules.

For example:

```
#map_canvas path:nth-child(57) {
fill:#cccccc;
}
```

Check out the last example of this page, from my website:
http://cmoreira.net/interactive-world-maps-demo/advanced-customization/

Hope it helps!
Cheers

Comment: I have to comment and say THIS IS BRILLIANT! I've been looking all morning for a way to color the states in my map in order to group states into regions AND keep the markers display. This solution is going to take some experimentation, but it fits the job perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I could do it by overlapping two charts one for region, one for markers
(using absolute divs with z-index)

you need to use transparent color as style for the marker layer
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        datalessRegionColor: 'transparent',
        defaultColor: 'transparent'
and put it on the top layer

Answer (score 0):

[VectorWorkz GeoChart](http://vectorworkz.com/) lets you define region color binding and marker binding within the same instance, take a look at the [VectorWorkz online demo](http://vectorworkz.com/demo/).

Answer (score -1):

or maybe put one chart with type "marker" over another of type "region" ? 
:)