# how to geochart countries and cities on a same map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, countries

I am facing a specific issue with the Geochart API from Google.
I want to Geochart countries, obviously, but several cities too.

These cities have a country code, but it doesn't work if I don't use "markers" mode anyway.

And if I use "markers" mode, it won't work for countries anymore as you can imagine.

So what should I do?
By the way, can I even do it?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use markers and cities in the same GeoChart.

This question has been asked before here:

[Google Geocharts: Regions and Markers on same map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650130/google-geocharts-regions-and-markers-on-same-map)

Answer (score 0):

"Yes, this is a limitation in Google GeoChart, you can however use [VectorWorkz GeoChart](http://vectorworkz.com/) which allows you to do this and more.